# Woocommerce disable grouped pricing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, price

I am looking for Woocommerce code to disable the pricing of a grouped product. I can't figure out where to disable it. Any suggestions?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Do you want to hide prices on grouped products or disable completely the price for one grouped product or on all grouped products? Why?

Comment: Hi sorry for not being clear.

i got a grouped product which lists two prices; the lowest and the highest of the products which are added to the specific group. i want to hide/ disable the lowest and highest price from showing up and only from the grouped product, not from the products which are in this group. I already adjusted the Class WC_Product_Grouped (https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Grouped.html) but without any luck. (My coding isnt that good :)) Let me know if you any more info! Thanks in advanced,